# How set environment variables in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How set  `ECLIPSE_HOME` variable .  and by default how it set by eclipse..?
...there is many variables `JRE_LIB,JRE_EXT,JUNIT_HOME`... and many more..
How these are set by eclipse and if some one wants to change it then what should he do..??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_run_env.htm).

Comment: actually i am using Rhino plugin in eclipse...  
to use java class in java script there is no problem when i just use class which is in RT.JAR. But when ever i want to use my class "custom classes" then problem begin due to classpath..
**Step make by me** 
1. make a class and put it into a jar file..  
2. add it into external jar in eclipse.  
3. use it into java script file and run Rhino debugger .  
4. error due to class not defined..."due to class path is not set properly"  
in javascript file i print classptha using systemclass method then it only print the path of rhino jar..  
plz help

Comment: Please update your question to include all this information along with the specific error message and the **relevant** part of your code (not all of it!) Actually, it might be better to post this as a new question.

Comment: plz check...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471093/how-set-classpath-for-rhino-debugger-plugin-in-eclipse